# Login not working in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I have used happy_seed gem and installed devise login. The app is working fine in development but when I deployed it to heroku it is giving me an error. I have checked the logs too but there is nothing helpful to debug that error.
Here is the app signup link http://radiant-lowlands-7232.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in

Comment: @IgorIvancha, would u mind changing your comment to answer. And can you explain me how did it work? Was not heroku supposed to do that all by itself or am I understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do `heroku run rake db:migrate`.
because all your migrates are only in `development`.
it helps you to create DB in `production`
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Answer (score 0):

It seems in your case

```
config.asset.compile = true
```

make It

```
config.asset.compile = false
```

Then

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Should Be work!!!